# Want to change the background of an div on hovering another div in css3

Tags: html, css, hover

I Want to change the background of a Div when Hovering over another Div and i tried

HTML5 part:

```html
<nav>
<div id="nav1"></div>
<a href="#"><div id="nav2"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="nav3"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="nav4"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="nav5"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="nav6"></div></a>
<div id="nav7"></div>
</nav>
<article>
<div id="nav8"></div>
</article>
```

And the CSS i tried is

```css
#nav2
{
float:left;
height:429px;
width:34px;
background:url(images/nav_02.gif) no-repeat;
}
#nav2:hover #nav8
{
float:left;
height:429px;
width:445px;
background:url(images/nav_08-nav_02_over.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

But it is not working ... 
I need to do it with css only no javascript ..

Comment: Your HTML looks dubious. You should probably be using something more like `<ul><li id="nav1"><a href="#"></a></li> .. </ul>`. Is changing your HTML an option? It also looks like you should be using a [CSS sprite](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/), instead of separate nav images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way CSS selectors works is `Parent > Descendant`

When you do

```
#nav2:hover #nav8
```

It means that #nav8 is a descendant of #nav2, which is not the case in your markup, so the rule does not apply

You have to use javascript to do what you're after.

Comment: Thank you actually that what i am confused !! whether it is possible or not to do such thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossibru. You can change the background of the div itself, and any child divs, when you are hovering it, but with a sibling/parent sibling/completely unrelated element - no way.

You could, however, do it in jQuery.

Example:

```
$("#nav2").mouseover(function() { 
    $("#nav8").addClass("someClassName");
});
$("#nav2").mouseout(function() { 
    $("#nav8").removeClass("someClassName");
});
```

And then hook up that background-image to #nav8.someClassName.

Answer (score 1):

Use this Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nav2").hover(function(){

    $("#nav8").css("background-image","url(images/nav_08-nav_02_over.jpg)");
    },function(){
    $("#nav8").css("background-image","");
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can add effects on same level tags in CSS3. On hover of a parent tag only child tags can have different CSS.

Answer (score 0):

it's impossible unless your `div` are siblings, so you can achieve the effect using

`+` [adjacent siblings selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) (css2) or 
 `~` [general siblings combinator](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators) (css3)

e.g. if your markup is structured in this way

```
<div id="nav1"></div>
<div id="nav2"></div>
...
<div id="nav9"></div>
```

you can apply some style to `nav2` hovering `nav1` with

```
#nav1:hover + #nav2 { ... }
```

because nav2 is an immediate (adjacent) sibling of nav1 (in this case `+` or `~` would have the same effect), or you can do the same on `nav9` hovering `nav1` with

```
#nav1:hover ~ #nav9 { ... }
```

(here you can use only the `~` selector.)
Note also that these selectors are available on all modern browser including Internet Explorer 7+, see http://html5please.us/#gtie6

Comment: Thanks but The problem is that they are not siblings.

Comment: @Princeyesuraj could you move every div id to its parent link?

Comment: no i cant. It will lead to more complexity since this is just a part of the code. I am just practicing HTML5 with CSS3 and trying to minimize the usage of JavaScript.