# How to change parent's CSS only when child is hovered?

Tags: css

As the title says.. I've a PARENT element that has a CHILD element (two divs here!)

I wanna change the background-color of the parent element when (AND ONLY WHEN) the child element hovered..

so if the parent element has padding and when cursor hovers on the padding the background color [css] doesn't change.. it only changes when the child is hovered..

Can I do it with css or I'll need some javascript?

Comment: Need javascript... Unless you were to put what looks like the parent, inside the child... o_O

Comment: You either need JavaScript, or change your markup. CSS doesn't "look up".

Comment: @bfavaretto CSS only cascades. :]

Comment: Check this previous SO discussion out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001229/want-to-change-the-background-of-an-div-on-hovering-another-div-in-css3

Comment: @CaseyChu thanks, that's much better phrased.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Complex CSS selector for parent of active child](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004/complex-css-selector-for-parent-of-active-child)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will indeed need javascript.  Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) for some good information about it.